# CORS policy returned from Lambda properly however client still gets Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make a simple call to my lamba endpoint that has a configured response to GET and OPTIONS calls.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://3yphvgt4dc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-cors/get-courses',
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'iSCourse': 'False',
            'Name': 'Ruth Anderson'
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

However every time this request gets sent from the client I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://3yphvgt4dc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-cors/get-courses' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Now here is what is interesting. To my knowledge I have configured the endpoint correctly and you can see that in the client

[image]

Here is the options call (as shown by the chrome network debugger)

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can see "access-control-allow-origin: *" set there.

However the error still comes through complaining about that issue.
[image]
[image]
[image]
The produced error is near the top of this post.

So overall I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out why the request is not going through in this situation. Any ideas?

Comment: 502 is a server-side error. You need to fix that first before addressing any client-side CORS issues.

Comment: Surprised this was closed as a duplicate, really disagree. In any event, in my experience, the behaviour of Lambda and API Gateway proxy integrations is exactly as you described when that header is missing in the response from the Lambda. Maybe his answer is right, maybe mine is, maybe something else; either way, hope you find the answer to your question.

Comment: Try to add these headers to your lambda response `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":  "*",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",`

Answer (score 0):

502 is server issue exactly. Should be fix that issue first and please ensure still cors is not working.

Answer (score -1):

The CORS error you are receiving is not a client side issue, its server side, as indicated by the error you are receiving:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is saying that the resource you requested, your Lambda via API Gateway, is not returning an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response.

To solve this issue, you need to do two things. First ensure CORS is enabled on your API Gateway (the response from the OPTIONS request suggests it is, but it should be verified).

Second, add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to the response your Lambda returns. You’ve not specified the language your Lambda is written in, but if it was in NodeJS, a snippet of what’s being returned might look something like:

```
    const result = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            // other required headers
        },
        body: object_you_are_returning
    };

    return result;
```

You can reference the AWS Docs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/) for more information on this error. In this case your error is a missing header, `access-control-allow-origin`, therefore adding this (and any other required headers) to the response will resolve the issue.